# Enabling or disabling WMS capabilities with python

Tags: python, arcgis-server, json, request

I am trying to enable `Feature Access` for all of my services on an ArcGISServer with python.  Below is my code.  The variable`json` is the `Feature Access` dictionary.  How do I make the post targeting that value in the `JSON`.  The status code of my post returns `200` but when I look at the `json` of the service it remains `false` and when I log into manager it is not enabled.

```
url = "https://xxx.com/arcgis/admin/services/folder/serviceXXX.MapServer/edit"
json_open = requests.get(url)
json_load = json_open.json()

json =  json_load["extensions"][5]
key = json_load["extensions"][5]['enabled']
update = json_load["extensions"][5]['enabled'] = "true"
print json
print "__________"


post = requests.request("POST", edit_url, data={'token': token, key: update, "f":"json"} )
print "________"

print post.status_code
```

json structure returned from variable `json`:

```
{u'allowedUploadFileTypes': u'', u'enabled': 'false', u'maxUploadFileSize': 0, u'capabilities': u'', u'typeName': u'FeatureServer', u'properties': {u'allowGeometryUpdates': u'false', u'realm': u'', u'allowOthersToUpdate': u'false', u'dataInGdb': u'true', u'datasetInspected': u'false', u'allowOthersToQuery': u'true', u'enableOwnershipBasedAccessControl': u'false', u'editorTrackingTimeInUTC': u'true', u'xssPreventionEnabled': u'true', u'allowTrueCurvesUpdates': u'false', u'zDefaultValue': u'0', u'editorTrackingRespectsDayLightSavingTime': u'false', u'allowOthersToDelete': u'false', u'enableZDefaults': u'false', u'creatorPresent': u'false', u'syncVersionCreationRule': u'versionPerDownloadedMap', u'editorTrackingTimeZoneID': u'UTC', u'syncEnabled': u'false'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have developed a [package](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS/restapi) to do these kinds of tasks on GitHub.  To enable/disable extensions, you can just do something like this:

```
from restapi import admin #can also use full namespace restapi.admin

# authentication params
url = 'http://someserver.yourdomain.com:6080/arcgis/admin/services'
usr = 'username'
pw = 'password'

# login to server, use username and password authenticate
arcserver = admin.ArcServerAdmin(url, usr, pw)

# get service by name or wildcard
service = arcserver.service('SampleWorldCities') # default ArcGIS Sample Service

# ext options: NAServer|MobileServer|KmlServer|WFSServer|SchematicsServer|FeatureServer|WCSServer|WMSServer
# enable extensions (options are not case sensative by the way)
service.enableExtensions(['FeatureServer'])

# disable Feature Access and WMS
service.disableExtensions(['FeatureServer', 'WMSServer'])
```

EDIT:

To Set capabilities for a newly initialized extension (such as Feature Server) you can do the following:

```
from restapi import admin

url = 'http://someserver.somedomain.com:6080/arcgis/admin/services'
usr = 'username'
pw = 'password'

# get ArcServerAdmin object
ags = admin.ArcServerAdmin(url, usr, pw)

# get service
service = ags.service('Some_Service_Name')

# enable feature access
service.enableExtensions('FeatureServer') #if just putting in one extension, it can be a single string, otherwise use list for multiple extensions

# now edit the service to include desired functionality for this service
service_json = service.response

# get reference to feature service extension
fs_extension = [e for e in service_json['extensions'] if e['typeName'] == 'FeatureServer'][0]
fs_extension['capabilities'] = 'Create,Query,Update,Sync,Delete'

# now do edit
service.edit(service_json) # this will make changes to service
```

I am glad you asked this.  I do not like how clunky this is.  I will implement some functionality to change these properties a little easier, probably using [Bunch](https://github.com/dsc/bunch) objects to represent the service json.

EDIT 2:

I have made some improvements for setting properties for a service, including a helper method for editing extensions.  I have added more code samples to the ReadMe on the GitHub page.  This is from the code sample:

```
# set properties for an extension using helper method, use **kwargs for setting capabilities
service.setExtensionProperties('FeatureServer', capabilities='Query,Update,Delete,Editing')

# verify changes were made in extension 
fs_extension = service.getExtension('FeatureServer')
print fs_extension.capabilities
# 'Query,Update,Delete,Editing'

# alternatively, you can edit the service json directly 

# change it back to original settings
fs_extension.capabilities = 'Query,Create,Update,Delete,Uploads,Editing'

# commit the changes by calling the edit method
service.edit()

# verify one more time...
print fs_extension.capabilities
# 'Query,Create,Update,Delete,Uploads,Editing'
```

Comment: This is awesome. Alternatively, consider using ArcREST - https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST/. Very powerful and fairly easy to get started, I use it daily.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov.  Yes, I have seen that before.  I did not know that it existed when I started writing this.  I have never been able to find any documentation on how to use `arcREST`, but it looks like some is provided now.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is not so great :) I have updated the wiki with some getting started guidance last year. I have also written tons of unit tests for ArcREST that can help people to get started, but don't have time to push it to some repo... :(

Comment: is it possible to set the operations allowed when enabling an extension? i.e: Create Query, update, sync, delete

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  See my edit, something like that should work.  As you're probably aware, enabling Sync has some extra requirements when building the service.

Comment: @Dan, see my edit # 2.  I just pushed some new changes to the repo on GitHub to include functionality shown above.  This should greatly simplify editing extension settings and service properties in general.