# Edit arcgis-service-properties with REST-API

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I want to change the properties of several services via REST-API with C#-HTTP-Client. Something goes wrong here so I tried first with Python.

I found the example [here on esri page](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/de/server/10.4/administer/windows/example-edit-service-properties.htm%20%22here%22.). For convenience I changed only the description. The output of python-script tells me all ok.

But in ArcGIS Server Manager and in JSON-LINK `(https://ip:6443/arcgis/rest/services/xxx/xxx/MapServer?f=pjson`) there is **no** change. 
But in the Administrator-Directory (`https://ip:6443/arcgis/admin/services/xxx/xxx.MapServer`) changes had been made.

So I thought something was wrong in the Server-Cache and made my script to stop and start the service...no success...started server also no success.

I found similar problem [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182722/enabling-or-disabling-wms-capabilities-with-python) but no reason for different reports in 
`ArcGIS Server Administrator Directory` and `ArcGIS Server Manager`.

Has anyone made similar experiences or knows a trick?